# Javascript Passing form Variable

Tags: javascript

Very new to Javascript, frustrated that I cannot seem to figure this question out as I know the answer is going to be something very basic!!!

I am trying to customize JCrop which is a image cropping tool.

I want to ask users for the size of a canvas before running Jcrop so that the cropping tool runs at a fixed ratio aspect depending on their form selection

The correct format of the image ratio needs to be 1/1, 1/2, 1/3  and has been set by my form.

```
            <select name="size" id="size">
                <option value="">Please select the size of your canvass</option>
                <option value="1/1">1x1</option>
                <option value="1/2">1x2</option>
                <option value="1/3">1x3</option>
                <option value="1/4">1x4</option>
                <option value="1/5">1x5</option>
                <option value="1/6">1x6</option>
            </select>


    <script language="Javascript">


    $('input[name=size]').click(function() {
    MethodTwo();
    });
function MethodTwo()
{
            var SIZEVARIABLE = $('#size').val();        
}
    // initialize Jcrop
            $('#preview').Jcrop({
                minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
                aspectRatio : SIZEVARIABLE, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
                bgFade: true, // use fade effect
                bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
                onChange: updateInfo,
                onSelect: updateInfo,
                onRelease: clearInfo
            }, function(){

                // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
                var bounds = this.getBounds();
                boundx = bounds[0];
                boundy = bounds[1];

                // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
                jcrop_api = this;
            });
        };
    </script>
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Evan Trimboli said, part of the problem is that you are passing strings instead of numbers for the `aspectRatio`.

The other part is that you are setting the `SIZEVARIABLE` property only when the user clicks the dropdown, so before that it is undefined. Also, using the `change` event is better for `select`s that `click`.

What you need to do when the dropdown is changed is actually call a different method to update the `aspectRatio` option of JCrop.

```
    <select name="size" id="size">
        <option value="">Please select the size of your canvass</option>
        <option value="1/1">1x1</option>
        <option value="1/2">1x2</option>
        <option value="1/3">1x3</option>
        <option value="1/4">1x4</option>
        <option value="1/5">1x5</option>
        <option value="1/6">1x6</option>
    </select>

<script language="Javascript">
$('select[name=size]').change(function () {
    MethodTwo($(this).val());
});

function MethodTwo(aspectRatioStr) {
    var parts = aspectRatioStr.split('/'),
        num = parseInt(parts[0]),
        denom = parseInt(parts[1]),
        newAspectRatio = num / denom;
    if (!jcrop_api) return;
    jcrop_api.setOptions({
        aspectRatio: newAspectRatio
    });
    jcrop_api.focus();
}

// initialize Jcrop
$('#preview').Jcrop({
    minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
    aspectRatio: 1, // start off with aspect ratio 1:1
    bgFade: true, // use fade effect
    bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
    onChange: updateInfo,
    onSelect: updateInfo,
    onRelease: clearInfo
}, function () {

    // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
    var bounds = this.getBounds();
    boundx = bounds[0];
    boundy = bounds[1];

    // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
    jcrop_api = this;

    MethodTwo($('#name').val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: One final comment: names of variables and functions are *super important* in programming. `MethodTwo` is a very poor name for a function as it tells you nothing about what it does. Instead, try calling it `changeAspectRatio()` or similar. The lowercase first letter is also normal JS convention for all functions that aren't intended to be used as constructors.

Comment: Hi Greg, really appreciate the time you took to explain this to me. It still seems to be running at a 1/1 ratio regardless of the dropdown that is selected. You can see an example of this script here http://ryanblundell.com/test/html5imageuploaderwithjcrop/

Comment: Okay, a few changes to be made: change `$('input[name=size]')` to `$('select[name=size]')` (my bad). Also, remove the second declaration of `jcrop_api`. Finally, at the bottom of the function passed to the `.Jcrop()` method, add a new line `MethodTwo($('#name').val())` to set the selected value as soon as the plugin is loaded (since the user can change the value before selecting an image). I made these changes to my answer.

Comment: Wow absolute genius! Thank you very much again (by the way, I made it to the end of your last blog post, its a subject I find very interesting!!). All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `aspectRatio` as a string. It needs a calculated number.

So the value in your select box should be:

```
<option value="1">1x1</option>
<option value="0.5">1x2</option>
<option value="0.33">1x3</option>
<option value="0.25">1x4</option>
```

You should also change the code that gets the number to use:

`var SIZEVARIABLE = parseFloat($('#size').val());`